# Alias / to /lang_code

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I got a multilanguage configuration with language detection based on URL(/en /fr). Drupal behavior redirects everything to so it would have those two prefixes or, if setup, it will ignore the prefix for a language while keeping for the other.

In my situation I need to keep the prefix for both language except for root page.

Ex:

- example.com/en -> will load english homepage
- example.com/fr -> will load french homepage
- example.com/ -> has to load english homepage but without redirect to /en

So, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal core doesn't redirect everything. Do you have the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module installed? Then disable the route normalizer in the module settings, which is by default enabled:

*/admin/config/search/redirect/settings*

> **GLOBAL REDIRECTS**
>
> [x] Enforce clean and canonical URLs

If you want to keep the global redirect try this module specifically for the language prefix [Disable Route Normalizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_route_normalizer).

Comment: That would imply that I need to make my homepage language neutral which is not the case.

Comment: No, you don't need to do this. You have the module Redirect installed?

Comment: yes I have redirect, but still not sure what is your point

Comment: It's the module Redirect redirecting everything and not Drupal. You can disable this behavior in the module settings.