# Multiple URLs for same node

Tags: 8, uri, path-aliases

anyone know how to create a URL alias and not redirect the user? I have a node with its alias set to `/sign-up`, but I also want it accessible via `/caregiver/sign-up`. I created a URL alias, but it seems to just do a redirect to `/sign-up`.

I checked the current redirects list and the only redirect for `sign-up` I am seeing as for an old page that redirects from `/activate` to `/sign-up`

Comment: This was a similar question for multiple URLs with and without language prefix https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269499/alias-to-lang-code

Comment: ^ That was the issue. I had to uncheck that

Answer (score 0):

- Get the node id that have /sign-up as alias (lets say it's node/42)
- Go to /admin/config/search/path/add
- Fill the form as mentioned in the description :
  Existing system path : /node/42
  Path alias : /caregiver/sign-up
- Save the form
- you can now access the node with /caregiver/sign-up alias :)

Comment: I had already created the URL alias as your answer is saying. I resolved this by unchecking `Enforce clean and canonical URLs.` in the url redirect setting sand then load an incognito window and it started working as it should. Only downside is I can view the page at say, node/12, and it doesn't redirect to the clean url. I think that is ok, I will just add a node/* deny  to my robots.txt file